# Negate GitHub search query for author in PR search

Tags: github

I'm trying to query PRs in the Github GUI based on certain criterias. I want to show all pull requests that have *not* been written by a certain author.

The following example would be a query that returns all PRs written by the author `mgol`:
https://github.com/pulls?q=org%3Ajquery+is%3Aopen+is%3Apr+author%3Amgol

I would now like to return all PRs in the `jquery` organization, but not the ones from `mgol`. I tried multiple things, adding `not:` and things like this, but nothing seems to just filter out the PRs by this single author.

Comment: `-author:mgol`? See https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax#exclude-certain-results

Comment: Ah thank you so much. I read the docs, I've seen the `NOT` and tried a lot with this, but I haven't seen the `-`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-author:mgol` to get negated searches. This applies to other searches, too (Issues, etc.). See https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax#exclude-certain-results for more.